# getting IndexOutOfBoundsException in between the game

Tags: java, exception, freeze

I made a game in which we control a spaceship and can shoot laser to destroy asteroids coming from top. But during game play, anytime it throws IndexOutOfBoundsException and my game get freezes. I don't know why it is happening. Please anyone tell me the solution. Thanks in advance! Here is my code(3 classes)

Class 1: Main Class

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Spacewar {
    Spacewar(){
        JFrame main=new JFrame();
        Gamefunction game=new Gamefunction();
        main.setTitle("SpaceWar");
        main.setVisible(true);
        main.setSize(1024,700  );
        main.setResizable(false);
        main.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        main.add(game);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Spacewar();
    }
}
```

Class 2: Game Functioning

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Gamefunction extends JPanel implements ActionListener,MouseListener,MouseMotionListener{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private static int width=1024;
    private static int height=700;

    private int time=5;
    private int score=0;
    private boolean play=false, gamestart=false, gameover=false ;
    private boolean shoot=false;

    Image bg,player,start;
    Timer timer;
    Rectangle bullet,ship;
    Random rand;
    ArrayList<Enemy> enemies;

    private int playerX = width/2-100;
    private int playerY = height-180;
    private int bulletX=playerX+45;
    private int bulletY=playerY-10;

    int total_enemies=190;

    Gamefunction(){
        //Loading Images 
        ImageIcon ibg=new ImageIcon("E:\\spacewar\\bg.jpg");
        bg=ibg.getImage();
        ImageIcon play=new ImageIcon("E:\\spacewar\\player.png");
        player=play.getImage();
        ImageIcon st=new ImageIcon("E:\\spacewar\\Start.jpg");
        start=st.getImage();

        //Main settings
        timer=new Timer(time,this);
        setFocusable(true);
        setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled (false );
        addMouseListener(this);
        addMouseMotionListener(this);
        rand=new Random();
        enemies = new ArrayList<Enemy>();
        timer.start();

        for(int i=0;i<total_enemies;i++){
            addEnemy(new Enemy(rand.nextInt(900),-rand.nextInt(1000)));
        }
    }
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);

        //background
        g.drawImage(bg, 0, 0, width, height, Color.black, this);

        //ship
        g.drawImage(player, playerX,playerY,100, 100, this);

        for(int i=0;i<enemies.size();i++){
            Enemy en =enemies.get(i);
            en.draw(g);     
        }

        if(!gamestart){
            g.drawImage(start, 0, 0, width, height, Color.black, this);
        }

        if(play){
            if(shoot==true){
                g.setColor(Color.green.brighter().brighter().brighter());
                g.fillRoundRect(bulletX, bulletY,6 , 15, 50, 100);
            }

            //score
            g.setColor(Color.white);
            g.setFont(new Font("Times new Roman",1,40));
            g.drawString("Score: "+score, 820, 50);
        }

        if(gameover){
            g.setColor(Color.white);
            g.setFont(new Font("Arial",1,150));
            g.drawString("Gameover", 150, 200);

            g.setColor(Color.white);
            g.setFont(new Font("Times new Roman",1,70));
            g.drawString("Your Score: "+score, 270, 280);

            g.setColor(Color.cyan);
            g.setFont(new Font("Times new Roman",1,100));
            g.drawString("Click to Restart", 200, 390);

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
        if(play){

            for(int i=0;i<enemies.size();i++){
                Enemy en =enemies.get(i);
                en.update();
            }

            for(int i=0;i<enemies.size();i++){
                bullet = new Rectangle(bulletX,bulletY,6,15);
                ship = new Rectangle(playerX,playerY,100,100);
                if(bullet.intersects(enemies.get(i).getEnRect())){
                    enemies.remove(enemies.get(i));
                    score++;
                    shoot=false;
                    bullet= new Rectangle(0,0,0,0);
                }
                if(ship.intersects(enemies.get(i).getEnRect())){
                    gameover=true;
                    play=false;
                }
            }

            if(playerX<0){
                playerX=0;
            }
            if(playerX>(width-100)){
            playerX=width-100;
            }
            if(shoot==true){
                bulletY-=30;

                if(bulletY<0){
                    shoot=false;
                    bulletY=playerY-10;
                    bulletX=playerX+50;
                }
            }
        }

        repaint();
    }

    public void shoot(){
        shoot=true;
        bullet = new Rectangle(bulletX,bulletY,6,15);
    }

    public void addEnemy(Enemy e){
        enemies.add(e);     
    }

    public void reset(){
        gameover=false;
        shoot=false;
        play=true;
        playerX = width/2-100;
        playerY = height-180;

        new Gamefunction();
    }   

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent me) {
        if(!gamestart){
            gamestart=true;
            play=true;
        }
        if(play){
            shoot=true;
        }
        if(gameover){
            reset();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent me) {
        if(play){
            playerX=me.getX();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent me) {
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent arg0) {

    }
    @Override
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

Class 3: Generating Asteroids/Targets

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;

public class Enemy {
    Random rand;
    int ex,ey;
    Enemy(int a, int b){
        ex=a;
        ey=b;
        rand=new Random();
    }


    public void update(){
        ey++;
    }

    public Image generateEnemy(){
        ImageIcon ast =new ImageIcon("E:\\spacewar\\ast.png");
        return ast.getImage();
    }

    public void draw(Graphics g) {
        g.drawImage(generateEnemy(), ex,ey, 80, 65, null, null);
    }
    public Rectangle getEnRect(){
        return new Rectangle(ex,ey,80,65);
    }
}
```

Here's the long Error Or Exception

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 170, Size: 170
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(Unknown Source)
    at Gamefunction.actionPerformed(Gamefunction.java:132)
    at javax.swing.Timer.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.Timer$DoPostEvent.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Please attach the exception you're getting

Comment: The error is caused most probably because you're removing elements from the `enemies` list while you're iterating it `enemies.remove(enemies.get(i));`. Use an `Iterator` instead of a normal `for` loop.

Comment: There is a difference between  `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` and `IndexOutOfBoundsException`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the for loop

```
for(int i=0;i<enemies.size();i++){
    bullet = new Rectangle(bulletX,bulletY,6,15);
    ship = new Rectangle(playerX,playerY,100,100);
    if(bullet.intersects(enemies.get(i).getEnRect())){
        enemies.remove(enemies.get(i));
        score++;
        shoot=false;
        bullet= new Rectangle(0,0,0,0);
    }
    if(ship.intersects(enemies.get(i).getEnRect())){
        gameover=true;
        play=false;
    }
}
```

You're continuing the loop until the original enemies size, but don't take into account that you actually reducing the list at the same time!

To accomplish that you will have to use an `Iterator`

```
for(Iterator<Enemy> iterator = enemies.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();){
    Enemy e = iterator.next();
    bullet = new Rectangle(bulletX,bulletY,6,15);
    ship = new Rectangle(playerX,playerY,100,100);
    if(bullet.intersects(e.getEnRect())){
        iterator.remove();
        score++;
        shoot=false;
        bullet= new Rectangle(0,0,0,0);
    }
    if(ship.intersects(e.getEnRect())){
        gameover=true;
        play=false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this line is giving you a problem:

```
enemies.remove(enemies.get(i));
```

In some cases you have already removed all enemies and again it tries to remove. Every time you access `enemies` make sure to check for the element that it is empty or has a value in it.

Answer (score 0):

```
 for(int i=0;i<enemies.size();i++){
            (...)
            if(bullet.intersects(enemies.get(i).getEnRect())){
                enemies.remove(enemies.get(i));
```

Here is some code from your main event handler. You are mutating the enemies array as you loop over it by removing items from the list. This will lead to IndexOutOfBounds exceptions.